# Do enemies in Academia 400 AF respawn?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I keep fighting them, but it seems like they would eventually stop spawning when there aren't any more people to turn into Cie'th unless the people respawn. I'm wondering whether it would be worth it to slow down and try to eliminate them all or if I should just try to get past as many as possible. Do they keep coming, or can I kill everyone eventually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot kill everyone. They will eventually respawn, and seeing as the cp rewards you get for them are almost non-existent, you are better off passing them by as fast as possible.

However, the Ghouls make one of the better opponents for farming Potent Drops just because they are so weak. Although I do recommend a Collector's Catalog because the drop rate is fairly low.

Comment: Isn't this area regarded as one of the best places to farm CP though?

Comment: No not at all you get from what i remember around 5 cp per fight.

Comment: I think it's more like 500?

Comment: "The easiest of ways is to get the CP Fragment Skill ‘Grow Egg’ and go to Academia 400AF to farm monsters. You can have up to 1000 CP per battle which lasts only few seconds."

Comment: I just checked the guide and ghouls do indeed have the lowest cp  reward in the entire game. about the other monsters there i dont know

Comment: Oh right Ghouls in particular, I just meant the general area. Apologies

Comment: i adressed ghouls in particular cause from what i remember those were the monsters that kept respawning